# SQL Server 2008 uniqueidentifier vs. Binary performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, binary, uniqueidentifier

In a logging perspective with millions of rows. What is the preferred way?

Do you store the Guid as a `UniqueIdentifier` or in `Binary`? Which is faster for searching?

The C# part of generating the values is not an issue here.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about indexes... I assume you do intend to index this column, right? Because that's *far* more important than choosing the right type (though the latter is also important).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A GUID *is* stored as binary but there are rules attached when comparing and sorting that are different to straight binary. See [How is a guid actually stored and sorted/compared in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945878/how-is-a-guid-actually-stored-and-sorted-compared-in-sql-server/6946661#6946661) for more

Whatever you choose, don't use a GUID a a clustered index. For why, see [What are the reasons *not* to use a GUID for a primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3050771/27535) as one example.