# How can a common "Attachments" table can be linked to several tables in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I have several entities that I want to give the possibility to store files. Like for a given customer, storing a copy of it's identity card or for a product, storing it's import documents and also quality certificates.

I don't want those files to be stored in the same entities rows and I've created a separate table for attachments. Decoupling it also gives the opportunity to later decide if I want to directly store the file, the storage location or some CMS access token.

So how I can make in EF for having such relationship between this attachments table and all the other tables that may have that functionalty?

An schema sample:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Attachment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //Relation property
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Add `public Attachment Attachment { get; set;}` to your class, what is confusing you?

Comment: You mean `public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }` ? The problem with that is that it doesn't join the tables by "ParentId" and then it does create a CustomerId, ProductId... one field for each linked table, in the attachments table.

Comment: Being a guid unique across tables, should be a way for resolving the relation with just one field in the destination table. Or I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

there are different possibilities to consider

### Method 1

make the attachment table to store the table name along with the id

then when you get some object `Product` check if it has an attachment using `ProdcutId` with the table name which is can be accessible using reflection

**Pros**:

- you get rid of the GUID which causes [some toubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050771/what-are-the-reasons-not-to-use-a-guid-for-a-primary-key)
- you have a simple table structure with only `Id` `RefrencedTable` `RefrencedId`

**Cons**

Accessing the Attachment list would perform a full table scan (you can minimize this impact using indexes) still you need to compare with the string `RefrencedTable`

### Method 2

defining an `Attachments` list in all needed tables which will create a foriegn key for each table

**Pros**

- easier access to the `Attachments` list from any other object
- still no Guid

**Cons**

possibly very large table with a lot of nullables and indexes

### Method 3

using shared GUID

**Pros**

- simple structure
- one index ([check more about clustered index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-guid-uuid-database-keys))

**Cons**

handling the GUID sequence which must be unique for all tables