# EF Core inferring relationship that it shouldn't

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have looked through various similar questions and none of them work for me I still get either that a one to one relationship between `CreateUser` and `ModifyUser` could not be determined or multiple navigations in entity type `User` pointing to same set of properties Id.

I use to be able to do to this just fine in every over version of EF Core but seems the .NET 6 version has an issue or I am still missing something.

```
## update 10/3
I just realized I forgot to add that the error is occurring when I try 
and build my migration.
```

These are my scrubbed entities and the configuration file I use for them:

```cs
public class BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id;
}

public class UserEditable : BaseEntity
{
    public Guid CreatedUserId;
    public Guid ModifyUserId;

    public User CreateUser;
    public User ModifyUser;
}

public class User : UserEditable
{
   //Various items
}

public abstract class BaseEntityConfiguration<T> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>
   where T : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder)
    {
        builder.haskey(k => k.Id);
    }
}

public abstract class UserEditable<T> : BaseEntityConfiguration<T>
  where T : UserEditable
{
    public override void Configure(entityTypeBuilder<T> builder)
    {
       builder.HasOne(o => o.CreateUser)
       .WithMany() //This could be various items thus it is left open.
       .HasForeignKey(f => f.CreatedUserId)
       .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.Id)
       .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
       
       builder.HasOne(o => o.ModifyUser)
       .WithMany() //This could be various items thus it is left open.
       .HasForeignKey(f => f.ModifyUserId)
       .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.Id)
       .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
    }
}

public class UserConfiguration : UserEditable<User>
{
    public overrider void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder);
    }
}
```

Comment: EF entity types need properties, not fields. Your `Guid Id` member is a field, not a property. Also, it's bad-practice to use the same name for an identifier in different types: if you see an `Id` property you have _no idea_ what it's for (a User? A document? etc?)

Comment: Also, using GUIDs for PKs is not as great an idea [because it wrecks index performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050771/what-are-the-reasons-not-to-use-a-guid-for-a-primary-key). SQL Server works-around this by using "sequential GUIDs" but many people (including myself) would argue they aren't "real" GUIDs because using sequential GUIDs introduces the risk of a collision.

Comment: @Dai I am using Sequential guid as its part of the config, just not shown, for the Id and it is fine to use Id as the PK due to if i say call user.id i know its the user id and if i link the User to another table in that table its called UserId.  As for you comments about type what are you referring to in my code above?  This is all structure correctly i am just not sure why now EF Core is now trying to infer a one to one between user.createuser and user.modifyuser.  I can always removed my baseentity and add id to everything like i did long ago but was trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF convention for auto-matching navigation properties is based on the property *type* not the property name. So for navigation properties:

```
public User CreateUser;
public User ModifyUser;
```

EF will be looking for FKs "UserId" and "UserId1" by default, not "CreateUserId" and "ModifyUserId" as you might expect, and certainly not "Create**d**UserId".  Explicitly tell EF which FKs to use:

```
public Guid CreatedUserId;
public Guid ModifyUserId;

[ForeignKey(nameof(CreatedUserId))]
public User CreateUser;

[ForeignKey(nameof(ModifyUserId))]
public User ModifyUser;
```

One reason I advise just always being explicit about the FK references rather than relying on EF convention. Convention may save time when it works, but can be a pain in the butt when it doesn't. :)

Comment: This was exactly what i missed due to i messed up another section so it ignored my reflections to the IEntityTypeConfiguration files.  I fixed that and everything came back up.  Call this a failure on myself.  I should learn to walk away for a bit as looking at the same code going its correct doesn't fix it.  LOL